# In angular2 how to detect shift key press on array key down press?

Tags: angular

I have a list of items and I am trying to give file traverse behavior like file explorer to the list of items meaning after selecting an item, if you hold shift  key and press down arrow those items should get selected.

I have a list as mentioned below.

```
<div class="container">
<ul class="mylist">
    <li  tabindex="1">item1</li>
    <li  tabindex="2">item2</li>
    <li  tabindex="3">item3</li>
    <li tabindex="4">item4</li>
    <li tabindex="5">item5</li>
    <li tabindex="6">item6</li>
    <li tabindex="7">item7</li>
    <li tabindex="8">item8</li>
    <li tabindex="9">item9</li>
    <li tabindex="10">item10</li>
</ul>
```

if I am using `(keydown.ArrowDown)="handleKeyEventDown($event, item.name)"`, its only recognizing arrow down event similarly keydown.shift recognizes shift key press. But if shift key is pressed I am not able to go the event for key down press. how to achieve this in angular2, please explain.

Comment: can you look at this one https://angular.io/guide/user-input

Comment: Looked. Thank you. But (keyUp) and (keyDown) will work for any keys, but not when you have pressed shift and you are hitting down arrow key.I need an event which trigers when the shift is pressed and either up arrow or down arrow key is pressed,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You start with event-type and add series of dot-delimited modifiers

Ex:
`keydown.shift.ArrowDown` Should do what you want.

Comment: How to do Ctrl+A key click in similar fashion?

Comment: @code1 similar as above, it would be just `keydown.control.a`

Comment: Thank you. I  was trying as keydown.ctrl.a and it was not working.